# upgrading to newer version of compiler

Tags: compiler, porting

I had legacy code that was originally build for some quite old version of compiler. We are talking about native code, not managed. Now it is ported to almost newest version of the compiler. Every compile error was fixed and now the product is properly compiling and running.

But:

- although it compiles and even runs... how can I be sure is is working as expected?
- can I be sure that underlying runtime does not change in a way that it introduces new and unexpected runtime bugs?
- what are best practices when upgrading to newer version of the compiler?

Comment: Testing, testing, testing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> although it compiles and even runs... how can I be sure is is working as expected?

The same way that you made sure the original code was working as expected. By extensively testing it.

> can I be sure that underlying runtime does not change in a way that it introduces new and unexpected runtime bugs?

You can never be 100% sure of that, but if it is a well-established compiler, you can be sure that both the compiler and the runtime environment have been extensively tested prior to their release.
This does not mean you are free of potential problems. It is still possible that you originally (unintentionally) depended on some undocumented/undefined behaviour that has been changed in the new release. You can only find that out by extensively testing your product.

> what are best practices when upgrading to newer version of the compiler?

You should treat it as a major systems change, similar to porting the application to a completely new platform.

Comment: hmmm... right! otherwise you need some 'formal' mathematical method to prove that new compiler does the same thing as previous one for the code. Testing is better way. Thanks for the valuable comment

Comment: If you are willing to pay the price, there *are* compilers for which such proofs are available.